# How to form the right URL structure for a REST/Json webservice for multiple query types

Tags: php, json, rest

I am managing a [Data Portal](http://geodata.grid.unep.ch/) where we want to add now a REST/Json webservice. The Portal has around 500 statistical data sets, nation by nation, worldwide, for multiple years, and with metadata for each data set.

The following questions should be able to be asked:

1. By sending an ID for a country, give me back a list of all data sets available for that country.
2. By sending an ID for a data set, give me back all metadata for that data set.
3. By sending an ID for a country and ID for a data set, give me back all data for that combination.
4. By specifying a time attribute (either a single year or a time period) along with a country ID and a data set ID, give me back all data for that time and country and variable.

I am not sure how the URL structure would look like.

Something like

```
 /countries/[iso code]/variable/[variable]/time/[time period]
```

or

```
 /countries/[iso code]/parameters/[parameter id]
```

?

What do you think? Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Forgot to mention that the Portal is programmed in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I would say try a framework like Laravel for this. the routes in Laravel make this very simple, and with the Eloquent ORM querying a DB is simple. You'll have to configure a few things but you should be able to code it in no time flat! Here's a link for the [Eloquent modeling](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent) and another for the [routes](http://laravel.com/docs/routing). For example to get functionality like you want on `/countries/[iso code]/parameters/[parameter id]` writing a simple route like:

```
Route::get('/countries/{iso}/parameters/{id}', function($iso, $id)
{
    //something along these lines
    $country = new country();
    $results = $country->find($iso);
    return Response::json($result);
});
```