# What is a good way to start developing a REST/Json webservice in PHP?

Tags: php, json, rest

In addition to an existing SOAP webservice, I'd like to offer a REST/Json webservice for our [Data Portal](http://geodata.grid.unep.ch/). However, I am not a real pro in PHP, and am new to REST/Json. I've looked quite a bit around, and things ain't look easy :-). I'd prefer some copy-/paste and customizing code in order to understand how it works over a framework. It won't be an over-complicated REST service, as you can see from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19903619/how-to-form-the-right-url-structure-for-a-rest-json-webservice-for-multiple-quer).

What would be your suggestions/adivces? Thanks for your help!

Comment: `What would be your suggestions/adivces?` Dont post question without a showing a minimum effort that you attempted to solve the problem.

Comment: As I have said, I've looked quite a bit around, and tried some PHP examples. But I found few really helpful tutorials. And I am not familiar with the existing frameworks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further looking quite a bit around, and based on [a good overview](http://davss.com/tech/php-rest-api-frameworks/) of PHP/REST/JSON API frameworks, I finally went with [Slim](http://www.slimframework.com/). It's really lightweight, it's pretty easy to learn once one gets a better understanding how those REST services work, although not much documentation and tutorials around. [Here](http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/12/restful-services-with-jquery-php-and-the-slim-framework/) is a useful one. [Here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-slim-rest/index.html). [Here](http://cacodaemon.de/index.php?id=48). And [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/writing-a-restful-web-service-with-slim/).

Hope this helps others.